# css put href parameter on entire div not only on text

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put an entire div inside an href parameter using CSS but it's not working when I want to give a color to my link.

```css
.nav_link a {color:#c2c2c2;text-decoration:none;}
.nav_link a:visited {color:#c2c2c2;}
.nav_link a:hover {color:#b1b1b1;}
```

```html
<a class="nav_link" href="#"><div class="nav_home">Link 1</div></a>
<a class="nav_link" href="#"><div class="nav">Link 2</div></a>
<a class="nav_link" href="#"><div class="nav">Link 3</div></a>
<a class="nav_link" href="#"><div class="nav">Link 4</div></a>
```

Comment: It's the opposite: `<div><a></a></div>`

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude but that gives link to text only. text that is inside div

Comment: Just learn how to use `display` property. You don't need the `<div>` tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove a tag from .nav_link a:hover , a_visited because .nav_link is a class of your a Tag =)

```css
.nav_link {
  color:#c2c2c2;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.nav_link:visited {
  color:#c2c2c2;
}
.nav_link:hover {
  color:#b1b1b1;
}
```

```html
<a class="nav_link" href="#"><div class="nav_home">Link 1</div></a>
    <a class="nav_link" href="#"><div class="nav">Link 2</div></a>
    <a class="nav_link" href="#"><div class="nav">Link 3</div></a>
    <a class="nav_link" href="#"><div class="nav">Link 4</div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

below is updated code

```css
.nav_link {
  color:#c2c2c2;
  text-decoration:none;
}
.nav_link:visited {
  color:#c2c2c2;
}
.nav_link:hover {
  color:#b1b1b1;
}
```

```html
<a class="nav_link" href="#"><div class="nav_home">Link 1</div></a>
    <a class="nav_link" href="#"><div class="nav">Link 2</div></a>
    <a class="nav_link" href="#"><div class="nav">Link 3</div></a>
    <a class="nav_link" href="#"><div class="nav">Link 4</div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS selectors are wrong. `a` has the class `nav_link`, so `.nav_link a` actually targets nothing. You can do `a.nav_link` or just `.nav_link`.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the hover to affect other elements' css, you'll need something like this:

```
a:visited > .nav{color:#c2c2c2;text-decoration:none;}
```

ie- when a is visited, change the color of the .nav element inside it.